# How can I rewrite this SQL using set based operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cross-join, cursors

I have below SQL query as part of a stored procedure in SQL Server. This is taking almost 20 minutes and sometimes more to run.

I tried to replace cursors with CTE (Common Table Expression) and have all the clustered and nonclustered indexes on the tables used in the below query.

After having all that, it is still taking too long to finish execution. Any help on making the below query execute faster would be highly appreciated. Thank you all in advance for your valuable suggestions and comments.

```
 DECLARE @ID as INT;  
 DECLARE @MyCursor as CURSOR;  
   
 SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR  
     SELECT ID  
     FROM dbo.table1
   
 OPEN @MyCursor;  
 FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @ID;  
   
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
 BEGIN  
     INSERT INTO table2(col1, col2, col3)  
         SELECT Rel.id, E.id2 AS col2, 1 AS col3
         FROM table3 AS Rel 
         JOIN  
             (SELECT R1.col 1 AS col1, R2.col2 AS col2
              FROM   
                  (SELECT TT.col1, TT.col2
                   FROM table4 AS TT 
                   JOIN table5 As Th ON Th.id= TT.id
                   WHERE Th.id= @ID) AS R1  
              CROSS JOIN  
                  (SELECT TT.col1, TT.col2
                   FROM table4  AS TT 
                   JOIN table5 AS Th ON Th.id= TT.id
                   WHERE Th.id= @ID) AS R2  
              WHERE 
                  R1.ID <> R2.ID) AS E ON E.ID1 = Rel.ID  
                                                     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                                                     FROM table6 
                                                                     WHERE ID = Rel.ID AND ID = E.ID2)  
  
     FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @ID;  
END  
   
CLOSE @MyCursor;  
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
```

Comment: CROSS JOIN take a lot of time for sure here , try change something there.

Comment: @Adamszsz the `CURSOR` is *far* worse. SQL is a set-based language, and a `CURSOR` is the completed opposite of that. The `CROSS JOIN` is unlikely to be the problem here. What happens, Vijay, if you do the entire `INSERT` in one go here?

Comment: Also how many rows are you expecting to create from this?

Comment: It feels like it would behoove you to consider a CROSS APPLY.   As stated above, CROSS JOINs can get rather expensive..    Also in the NOT EXISTS  consider SELECT 1 rather than SELECT *

Comment: @Larnu, entire insert in one go how is it possible? because it is taking each row from cursor and inserting. john CROSS APPLY is similar to CROSS JOIN?

Comment: @VijayAnde you write a single query which obtains the results you want to insert, and you insert them in one go, rather than using a cursor. Insert works with multiple rows.

Comment: It would also help if you explain what you are trying to do... it seems you want every combination of `TheTag` for a given group or something?

Comment: @DaleK, i have no idea what this query doing i was told to tune this query as it is taking too long to execute in prod. can you share a sample query that gets me records that matches about 900 rows.

Comment: @VijayAnde well if I was tasked to make changes to a query, the first thing I would do is gain a basic understanding about what the query is attempting to accomplish, and setup a [mre] with test data so that I can test it, tune it, and ensure I haven't broken it. I've given you a sample query in an answer below.

Comment: @DaleK, nothing like that might be those answers didn't work for me.

Comment: @VijayAnde if you're not getting the answer you want, you should continue commenting under the answer. Its pretty rare that you'd ask that many questions and not get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove the cursor by having your `CROSS JOIN` join *all* groups, ensuring to match the `Tag` to the correct `GroupID` as shown in the following snippet:

```
SELECT R1.col1, R2.col2 
FROM (
    SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1
    FROM table1 AS t1
    JOIN table2 As t2 ON t2.id= t1.id
    
) AS R1  
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1
    FROM table1 AS t1
    JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id= t1.id
    
) AS R2  
WHERE R1.id<> R2.id
-- Ensure the Group is the same
AND R1.id= R2.id;
```

Once working in a single statement then you are in a much better position to performance tune it.

Comment: @VijayAnde as I said, this may not solve the performance issue, but its the first step... the key point is whether it produces the desired results without the use of a cursor. If it does, then you need to post an execution plan to see what it taking too long.

Comment: @VijayAnde maybe, but without seeing it I can't comment.

Comment: ok Dale, its too late to me here in India. I will post the execution plan. Is it okay to you if I send an email to you?

Comment: @VijayAnde sorry no, I don't do private consultations for free, you need to update your question. I recommend posting the execution plan for the non-cursor version as that offers the best potential for improvement.

Comment: @VijayAnde use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ because I can't read that image. And just pop the link in a comment.

Comment: Use the link to paste the plan. Click the instructions link to learn how to use it.

Comment: @VijayAnde why are you trying to delete the query from my answer?

Comment: @VijayAnde if you're trying to remove your post because you "accidentally" posted confidential code then you need to raise a moderator flag and request that they help you - because its not something you can do yourself. The entire edit history is saved anyway, so editing it just hides it. That said, your code doesn't appear to contain any secrets to me.

Comment: ok, thanks Dale. How do i raise a moderator flag please advise.

Comment: @VijayAnde I've just approved it - although you do realise the edit history remains? So anyone can view how it used to be.

Comment: Is there a way to remove or change the edit history @Dale please advise.

Comment: @VijayAnde I did advise - you have to flag it for moderator attention. And/Or you can ask on meta.stackoverflow.com and read existing posts e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253717/if-you-accidentally-added-confidential-information-on-stack-exchange-can-you-ha